# Use of swift in existing objective c project

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and am trying to use swift in my project. I've added a new UIViewController which uses swift in my project (Objective-c). It's working fine but I can't import other objective - c files header in that swift file. Is there any other way to access other objective-c ViewControllers?

Comment: Yes, you have to add them to the bridging header. There is a large section about it in the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) and multiple answered questions on SO too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Objective C code from Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)